# Moving a Character Between Levels/Rooms

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a 2d platformer that draws rooms from an xml file.  The xml file contains usual things such as locations of enemies and tiles, as well as their texture mappings.

In a typical "Metroidvania" game the player will move to the edge of one room which will load the adjacent room.  My question is general:

**How can I communicate which room my character is walking into from the currently-loaded room?**

Right now every room is in an individual xml file, and there may be more than one exit per room (a room with a large perimeter may have multiple exits per direction down/up/left/right).  I'm thinking some sort of graph theory is appropriate but I am unable to find examples of how to implement this in C++ or SFML 2.1.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to give each room an identifier (a number, name, whatever) and have each door store the identifier of the room that it leads to. Have you considered this solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the idea of triggers, which are heavily used in a lot of games. They're generally collidable objects that have no graphical representation. So in a 2D platformer, it would be an invisible box that does something when a particular object collides with it.

Setting up your triggers is just like setting up other objects, but just not drawing it. Make sure it checks if the player has collided with it, and if it does then execute its action. You can have a trigger to go to one room, and another trigger for a different room, etc.

```
class TriggerBase
{
    Rectangle _bounds;

    void CheckAgainst( IObjectWithPosition* object ) const
    {
        if( object->X >= _bounds.Left &&
            object->X <= _bounds.Right &&
            object->Y >= _bounds.Top &&
            object->Y <= _bounds.Bottom )
        {
            ExecuteTrigger( object );
        }
    }

    virtual void ExecuteTrigger( IObject* object ) const = 0;
};
```

The idea is to have a list of these triggers, and loop through them, checking against objects that actually need to be checked against. This is a rough base to go from, but it provides the basic idea.

Comment: This is very good.  I'm thinking about adding a "trigger" member to my Tile class so that I can give certain tiles a non-empty trigger property which will contain the file name of the next room to load.  Then this can be part of collision-detection cycle, and upon collision the current room is unloaded and the new room loaded.

Comment: That will work, but you may want to abstract the trigger system away from the layout system. It'll be more extensible and organized. Then you won't have to couple the trigger logic to, say, the platform logic.

Comment: That makes sense, it will be better to place an invisible object separately from placing tiles.  I will likely add a new xml node which contains the position and room-links of these invisible trigger objects - thanks for the help.